# Get specific data from URI

Tags: c#, uri

I wanted to get the following data from the url

> 1. the service name which is in this case - customer
>
> 2.client which is 177

the structure is the the same always and the name of the service and client can be changed

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://ldcorp:435/mtp/op/ota/ind/Customer/?my-client=177");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uri.Segments.LastOrDefault()` returns `"Customer/"`

`uri.Query` returns `"?my-client=177"`

You can use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (System.Web assembly) to parse the query.

```
var result = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
string client = result["my-client"];
```

Comment: thanks DIRK voted up ,there is a way to get just "177"

Comment: `ParseQueryString` returns a `NameValueCollection`, you can use that to get `"177"` with the `["my-client"]` indexer on the return value.